# Socket exception when putting data on Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are inserting 20000 records into dynamo db using single insertion. There are 10 concurrent requests at a given point of time. Each item size is around 200-300kb in size. However, we keep getting **SocketException:Connection reset** when doing the insertion. Also the log shows it as INFO, so does this mean that DynamoDB API will retry the request automatically? What happens to the data that was sent with this request.

Following is the stacktrace:

```
Mar 04, 2015 6:17:23 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:377)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:363)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:837)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:808)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
at org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:142)
at com.amazonaws.http.RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.writeTo(RepeatableInputStreamRequestEntity.java:153)
at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:47)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:682)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3106)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.putItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1206)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.PutItemImpl.doPutItem(PutItemImpl.java:87)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.PutItemImpl.putItem(PutItemImpl.java:41)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.putItem(Table.java:126)
at awsdynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBAPIImpl.saveItem(AmazonDynamoDBAPIImpl.java:71)
at awsdynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBUtil.saveItem(AmazonDynamoDBUtil.java:144)
at dynamodbdatamigration.CopyFailedRecords.processItems(CopyFailedRecords.java:64)
at dynamodbdatamigration.CopyFailedRecords.run(CopyFailedRecords.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamo will not retry automatically.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#AmazonDynamoDBClient(com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials,%20com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/retry/RetryPolicy.html

You can configure a RetryPolicy via the ClientConfiguration when building the client.

In your particular case I am guessing the server decides that the connection is taking too long and resets the connection.

I would advise breaking this down the insert into multiple inserts.

Data that was successfully sent with the insert is probably in Dynamo.

Comment: DynamoDB **does** retry automatically in the default configuration in certain cases. See the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.java#L388-L396) for where it is configured, and the [DYNAMODB_DEFAULT `RetryPolicy`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/cf21041bc0129512cd30431fc4a960f9e73e6cbc/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/retry/PredefinedRetryPolicies.java#L103-L108) is configured. It probably just isn't retrying or went through all retries.

Comment: agree, but by default the client config is not setup for retries.

Comment: It does retry automatically: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html#APIRetries You have to manually turn it off by setting the parameter to 0